# Yii2 Simple Ad Hoc Validation

Tags: php, validation, yii2

I create a simple validation like :

```
public function actionMerchant() {

    $post = Yii::$app->request->post();

    $model = DynamicModel::validateData($post, [
        [['mid'], 'required'],
        [['mid'], 'integer'],
        ['email', 'email'],
    ]);

    if ($model->hasErrors()) {
        return [
            "message" => "Validation fail. Please check your input!"
        ];
    }

    return $model;
}
```

From the above code, I expect if I send the post parameters for both mid and email parameters, both parameters can be validated by the DynamicModel class.

The problem I get, what if I **only** send **email** parameters **without** mid parameters?

I will get `Getting unknown property: yii\\base\\DynamicModel::mid` error message.

Does the **require validation** not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Require validation works fine. Problem is in your `DynamicModel`, because Yii2 is creating it object attributes from first parameter you pass (for your example thats your `$_POST` attributes). To make it work correctly, first define model attributes, then load values to it, and then validate.

More in [DynamicModel Yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-dynamicmodel.html)

=== EDIT ===

```
$model = new DynamicModel(['mid' => null, 'email' => null]);
$model->addRule('email', 'email');
//here add more rules
$model->load($post);
$model->validate();
```

Comment: You mean like `compact('mid', 'email')` ? Based on my code above

Comment: With you code, I always get Validation error. My code : https://pastebin.com/fXP6dh28  FYI: I send request not from Yii form, but Postman : https://ibb.co/bJgV7b

Comment: Use `$model->load($post, '');`, should be fine.